# How to make list of friends private in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy, friend-list

One of the Facebook apps I wanted to install had a list of permissions it asked to have grante. One of the permissions is my list of friends, which I refused. It seems the list is public.

How do I make it private?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to your profile
2. Click on the **Edit Profile** button, in the upper-right corner
   [image]
3. Go to **Friends and Family**
   [image]
4. At the **Friends** section, click on the visibility icon ([image])
   [image]
5. Choose **Only Me**